Canvas app People combo box not selecting the person
My Canvas app has a form that binds to a sharepoint list MySharepointList that has a People column (column User).
This User column is a combo box (combo) in the Canvas app form.
I set combo.Items to this
Filter(
Office365Users.SearchUserV2(
    {
        searchTerm: Trim(Self.SearchText),
        isSearchTermRequired: false
    }
  ).value,
  AccountEnabled = true && Not("#EXT" in UserPrincipalName)
)

When I run it, it does show a list of people and I am able to select the people.
But, when I type a person name, and select it, it doesn't select it.
How can I fix it ?
Thank you
